# Trying to call variable from one python script to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, keyword-argument

I am trying to import variables from one Python script to another. I would normally do `from file1 import function1` to import function to another script or function.

However, the function1 in file1 is defined using `**kwargs` so when I try to do the below

`from file1 import function1`

I get an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'function1' from 'file1' (script.py)
```

Given below is how `function1` is defined

```
def function1(**kwargs):
    name = kwargs['customer_name']
    date = kwargs['sale_date']

    variable_name = xyz

    ----Remainder of the python script-----
```

I am trying to call that `variable_name` in a new python script/function.

Comment: `**kwargs` has nothing to do with this problem. Maybe you have `file1.py` without function `function1` - so it can't import it

Comment: `variable_name` is local variable and you should use `return variable_name` inside `function1` and get it outside using `variable_name = function1()`. OR you would have to use `global variable_name` inside `function1` to assign `xyz` to external/global `variable_name` but it would get it after running `function1` so better use `return variable_name`

Comment: BTW: `import` is looking for `file1.py` in folder in which you run code (so called Current Working Directory) if you run code in different folder then it may find different `file1.py` which doesn't have `function1` - check `print( os.getcwd() )`